# Uk Music concert sales data

Tags: json, database

Where can I find open source historic **data** of **attendance** figures or **sales** volumes for musical concerts/gigs/festivals in the **United Kingdom**?

Comment: Not here.  Read [ask]

Comment: Asking for off-site resources is off-topic. SO is not a link aggregator.